# Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at mksmksmks.pl line 63

Tags: perl, initialization

I have written some code, and I am not sure what the error is. I am getting the error:

> Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at mksmksmks.pl line 63

My code is as follows:

```
for(my $j = 0; $j < $num2; $j++) {
  print {$out} "$destination[$j]|$IP_one_1[$j]|$IP_one_2[$j]|$reached[$j]|$IP_two_1[$j]|$IP_two_2[$j]\n";`
}
```

Comment: and my line 63 is the one which consists of the for loop

Comment: It's impossible to tell which value is uninitialized from what you've shown us. Use the Perl debugger or add some `print` statements and examine the values of all the variables referred to in your (very long) string literal; one of them is `undef`.

Comment: And a sidenote: perhaps it's better to reorganize your data from 5 arrays into array of hashes? It'll be way more cleaner to process, I suppose.

Comment: In recent versions of Perl (from 5.10, I think) that warning is improved so that it tells you which of the values is undefined. Yet another good reason to upgrade :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What it means is that one of the elements of either `@destination`, `@IP_one_1`, `@IP_one_2`, or `@reached` has not been defined (has not been assigned a value), or has been assigned a value of `undef`.  You either need to detect (and prevent) undefined values at the source, or expect and deal with them later on.  Since you have `warnings` enabled (which is a good thing), Perl is reminding you that your code is trying to concatenate a string where one of the values being concatenated is undefined.

Consider the following example:

```
perl -wE 'my @x = (); $x[0] = "Hello "; $x[2] = "world!";  say "@x"'
```

In this example, `$x[0]` has a value, and `$x[2]` has a value, but `$x[1]` does not. When we interpolate `@x` into a double-quoted construct, it is expanded as `[element 0 (Hello )]<space>[element 1 (undef)]<space>[element 2 (world!)]`.  The `undef` elements interpolates as an empty string, and spews a warning.  And of course by default array interpolation injects a space character between each element.  So in the above example we see `Hello <interpolation-space>(undef upgrades to empty string here)<interpolation-space>world!`

An example of where you might investigate is one or more of the arrays is of a different total size than the others.  For example, if `@IP_one_2` has fewer elements than the others, or if `$num2` is a value greater than the number of elements in any of the arrays.

Place the following near the top of your script and run it again:

```
use diagnostics;
```

When I run the following one-liner under warnings and diagnostics:

```
$ perl -wMdiagnostics -e '$a=$a; print "$a\n"'
```

I get the following output, and you will get something similar if you add `use diagnostics;`... a very helpful tool when you're first learning Perl's warnings.

> Use of uninitialized value $a in concatenation (.) or string at -e
>   line 1 (#1)
>
> (W uninitialized) An undefined value was used as if it were already
>      defined.  It was interpreted as a "" or a 0, but maybe it was a mistake.
>      To suppress this warning assign a defined value to your variables.
>
> To help you figure out what was undefined, perl will try to tell you
>      the name of the variable (if any) that was undefined.  In some cases
>      it cannot do this, so it also tells you what operation you used the
>      undefined value in.  Note, however, that perl optimizes your program
>      anid the operation displayed in the warning may not necessarily appear
>      literally in your program.  For example, "that $foo" is usually
>      optimized into "that " . $foo, and the warning will refer to the
>      concatenation (.) operator, even though there is no . in
>      your program.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe my example will be useful to someone. Suppose variable $x is initialized from a database. It may contain an undefined value, and this is normal. We need to display its value on the console. As responsible programmers, we decided to use "use warnings FATAL => "all";". In this case, the script will fail.

```
perl -e 'use strict; use warnings FATAL => "all"; my $x; print("x=$x\n"); print("DONE\n");'
```

Returns:

```
Use of uninitialized value $x in concatenation (.) or string at -e line 1.
```

In this case, you can use

```
if(defined($x)){...}else{...}
```

But this is not pretty if just want to print a value.

```
perl -e 'use strict; use warnings FATAL => "all"; my $x; print("x=".($x//"null")."\n"); print("DONE\n");'
```

Prints:

```
x=null
DONE
```

Because the expression $x//"null" checks whether what comes before // is defined and if it is not defined returns what comes after //.

Answer (score -1):

If you use `eq ""` it won't give any warning message.

But if you use `eq " "` (here you can see a space), then it will give this warning message:

> Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string ....